# Use rust-s3 without tokio?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to use the [`rust-s3`](https://crates.io/crates/rust-s3) crate in the simplest & lightest possible way (w/o async). By default this crate uses `tokio`. So I followed what's written in `rust-s3`'s [README](https://github.com/durch/rust-s3#readme):

> With `default-features = false`
>
> - `sync` - no async runtime, `attohttpc` is used for HTTP requests

So in my `Cargo.toml` I added this:

```
[dependencies]
rust-s3 = { version = "0.28.1", default-features = false, features = ["sync"] }
```

When I read "no async runtime", I don't expect to see `tokio` added as a dependency. However, `tokio` is still being added. And looking at the crate's `Cargo.toml`, I see it has a (non-optional) dependency on `tokio-stream`, which, in turn, depends on `tokio`. This is from `cargo tree`'s output in my project:

```
├── tokio-stream v0.1.8
│   ├── futures-core v0.3.19
│   ├── pin-project-lite v0.2.8
│   └── tokio v1.15.0
│       └── pin-project-lite v0.2.8
```

So it seems to me it's actually not possible to avoid *adding* `tokio` as a dependency, the way this crate is written. Am I right or am I missing something here?

Comment: Seems to be an oversight. The `tokio_stream` dependency seems to only be used in `src/request.rs`, which is only included if the feature `with-tokio` is active, which `sync` doesn't activate. You'd likely have to open an issue in their github to be sure though.

Comment: FYI there is currently a build error when using the plain "sync" feature without explicit TLS opt-in: https://github.com/durch/rust-s3/issues/354
At least for 0.33.0 `sync-native-tls` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I kinda reached the conclusion `tokio` in its default mode has almost nothing (no runtime, etc.), so maybe that's why, even though it is included as a dependency, it shouldn't add much of a baggage in itself.